# Extension method for Null handling not working on linq for xml

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I have an nullexception issue when trying to get the value of an xml tag, which is under a subtree that may not be there.

The extension handler works great when it can't find a tag on an existing subtree, but seems to not be able to handle when looking for a tag in a subtree that doesn't exist.

In this case, the subtree is summaryData, which may or not be there, and trying to get addressLine1 is where it doesn't handle the `null`, and I get the error

> System.NullReferenceException occurred, Message=Object reference not
>   set to an instance of an object.

Here is the xml, cut down for clarity, but structure is correct:

```
 <record>
  <accounts>
    <account >
    </account >
  </accounts>
  <summaryData>
    <Date>2013-02-04</Date>
    <address >
      <city>Little Rock</city>
      <postalCode>00000</postalCode>
      <state>AR</state>
      <addressLine1>Frank St</addressLine1>
    </serviceAddress>
  </summaryData>

</record>
```

My C# code is:

```
 xmlDoc.Descendants("account")
                //select (string)c.Element("account") ;
                select new
                {
                    //this works fine
                    Stuffinxml = c.Element("stuffinxml").Value,
                    //this field may not be there, but the handler handlers the exception correctly here when it as the correct root (account)
                    otherstuff = CustXmlHelp.GetElementValue(mR.Element("otherstuff")),
                    //this is the problem, where the summaryData root does not exist (or moved somewhere else)
                    street_address = GetElementValue(c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1"))

                };
```

My extension method to handle a null is:

```
 public static string GetElementValue(this XElement element)
    {
        if (element != null)
        {
            return element.Value;
        }
        else
        {
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated, as I can't see why it fails when the subtree does not exist.

Comment: You pass in c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1"), could the null come from any one of these intermediate elements being missing. The null check in your method is only checking the last one (the one that is actually passed into the method for null)

Comment: Your sample xml is invalid - `address` tag - is that a typo or an actual record?

Comment: You are correct, I cut it down too much and removed the ending address tag.  Typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The summary data may or may not be there

That's why. As you're nesting calls, you'll have to null check them **all**.

Any one of these could be null:

```
c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1")
```

Without a complex conditional, there's not a *nice* way around it:

```
street_address = c.Element("summaryData") != null
    ? c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress") != null
        ? GetElementValue(c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1"))
        : string.Empty
    : string.Empty;
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense.  I guess I could also pass the summaryData element to the extension method, and if it is not null, then go dig for the addressLine1 in the extension method, though not sure that is any cleaner.

Comment: @user1644147 You could and it would be cleaner, but then that method would only really be useful for the summaryData element, it wouldn't be generic. Best leave it like it is above :)

Answer (score 1):

If the `summaryDate` element does not exist then

```
c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1")
```

will throw a `NullReferenceException` because you're trying to call `Element()` on a null reference (`c.Element("summaryData")`)

Answer (score 1):

As had been stated, your exception is due to the fact that you are passing multiple nested queries

```
c.Element("summaryData").Element("serviceAddress").Element("addressLine1")
```

is the equivalant of writing:

```
var x1 = c.Element("summaryData");
var x2 = x1.Element("serviceAddress")
var x3 = x2.Element("addressLine1")
```

So if any of `c`, `x1`, or `x2` are null, you are going to get a `NullReferenceException`.

One possible alternative to a pure `LINQ` solution using multiple null checks, is to use `XPath` to build the expression.

With `XPath`, rather than doing a null check at every level, you can instead write your expression:

```
street_address = GetElementValue(c.XPathSelectElement("/summaryData/serviceAddress/addressLine1"))
```

This will evaluate the entire expression and if it does not exist in its entirety, it will return `null`, but will not thrown an exception like your pure LINQ query.